# Is "make a difference" fit to this conditions?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

I want to make a slogan in English. What I want is, my brand slogan is grammatically correct and accordance  to below conditions.

1. Following brand names, like:

> [BRAND NAME]. [slogan]

2. Sentence patterns (inspired by "keep calm and ...")

> You sleep, I code. I [slogan]
>
> You are sleeping, I am working. I [slogan]

3. Even printed-out independent typography design on a product (like "JUST DO IT")

My current work for my brand slogan is "**make a difference**". So, if this slogan applies to the conditions above, it's like:

> [BRAND NAME]. **Make a difference**
>
> You sleep, I code. I **make a difference**
>
> You are sleeping, I am working. I **make a difference**
>
> Printed out a "**Make a difference**" on a Tshirt

Other people say it's right. But in point one, It must use "makes", not "make". That's not what I want, because I just want to create one slogan, for consistency.

Is the "**make a difference**" grammatically correct to above conditions? or there is a sentence closest to this one? thanks in advance.

Comment: if you just say 'make a difference' then it is imperative, so you are telling somebody to make a difference. That sounds right to me in that case, but it might be helpful to have a little more context in terms of what meaning you want.

Comment: Does "just do it" is imperative sentence?

Comment: FYI, my brand is about clothes. I want my customer feels difference when using my products.

Comment: Yeah make a difference would mean you were literally were telling them to make a difference. Just do it would also be imperative, also that's already a slogan for some sportswear company or other

Comment: I also think your “Make a difference.” is perfectly idiomatic as an imperative slogan, just like “Just do it.” By searching online, you will notice that “Make a difference.” is used by many other businesses/organizations.

Comment: @Orbital Aussie is "perfectly idiomatic" mean a positive thing?

Comment: Yes, positive. Idiomatic expressions are those that are natural, ordinary and frequently used by a native English speaker.